# Pointer returned by unique_ptr<T>::get() is not nullptr after original unique_ptr is destroyed

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr

I have a global vector of unique_ptrs to a base class, to which I append unique_ptrs to a derived class:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> global_vec;

template<typename T>
Base* create_object()
{
  std::unique_ptr<T> uptr = std::make_unique<T>(/* ... */);
  Base* last_ptr = uptr.get();
  global_vec.emplace_back(std::move(uptr));
  return last_ptr; /*this is a bit irrelevant, but is for the caller*/
}
```

Now, Base itself has a member vector of raw pointers to Base:

```
struct Base
{
  ...
  std::vector<Base*> providers;
  ...
}
```

The pointers that make up Base::providers are all obtained via calling unique_ptr::get() from global_vec:

```
void Base::subscribe_to(Base* src)
{
  providers.push_back(src);
}
```

Base has a member function that does work with these subscribers, and checks for nullptr before doing work:

```
void Base::do_work()
{
  ...
  for(Base* ptr : providers)
  {
    if(ptr != nullptr)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now, somewhere else in my code, I can erase the unique_ptrs in global_vec:

```
auto itr = std::find_if(global_vec.begin(), global_vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Base> const& n)
        { return n.get() == ptr_selected; }); //ptr_selected points to a widget selected by the user
  global_vec.erase(itr);
```

However, after erasing an element, Base::suscribers will still hold a valid pointer to an object. That is, when iterating through Base::providers in Base::do_work(), no Base* will equal std::nullptr.

I would expect that erasing a unique_ptr from global_vec would invoke Base::~Base(), thus rendering the pointers in Base::providers as std::nullptr. Base's destructor is invoked, but the pointers are valid (you can even get access to data members from them).

Base does have a virtual destructor.

Why are the pointers in Base::providers still valid?

Comment: `get` returns by value!

Comment: Destroying an object has no effect on pointers to that object except making dereferencing them undefined. And undefined may seem to work, occasionally (there is no way to determine whether a pointer is valid).

Comment: Pointers are one way. There is no backchannel to update other pointers to the same object. The book-keeping to implement such a channel would be impractical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would expect that erasing a `unique_ptr` from `global_vec` would invoke `Base::~Base()`

Yes, it does.

> thus rendering the pointers in `Base::providers` as `std::nullptr`.

This is where your expectation fails.  There is no way for **raw** pointers to an object to be set to `nullptr` automatically when the object is destroyed.  It is *YOUR* responsibility to handle that manually in your own code.  You need to remove a `Base*` pointer from the `providers` vector before/when the corresponding object is destroyed.  The compiler cannot do that for you.

You might consider having two `vector<Base*>` in your `Base` class, one to keep track of objects that `this` has subscribed to, and one to keep track of objects that have subscribed to `this`.  Then, `~Base()` can unsubscribe `this` from active subscriptions, and notify active subscribers that `this` is going away.  For example:

```
struct Base
{
...
protected:
    std::vector<Base*> providers;
    std::vector<Base*> subscribers;
    ...

public:
    ~Base();

    ...

    void subscribe_to(Base* src);
    void unsubscribe_from(Base* src);

    ...
};

Base::~Base()
{
    std::vector<Base*> temp;

    temp = std::move(providers);
    for(Base* ptr : temp) {
        unsubscribe_from(ptr);
    }

    temp = std::move(subscribers);
    for(Base* ptr : temp) {
        ptr->unsubscribe_from(this);
    }
}

void Base::subscribe_to(Base* src)
{
    if (src) {
        providers.push_back(src);
        src->subscribers.push_back(this);
    }
}

void Base::unsubscribe_from(Base* src)
{
    if (src) {
        std::remove(providers.begin(), providers.end(), src);
        std::remove(src->subscribers.begin(), src->subscribers.end(), this);
    }
}

void Base::do_work()
{
    ...
    for(Base* ptr : providers) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> global_vec;
```

Otherwise, consider using [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of `std::unique_ptr` in your global vector, and then you can store `std::weak_ptr<Base>` objects instead of raw `Base*` pointers in your other vectors.  When you access a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), you can query it to make sure the associated object pointer is still valid before using the pointer:

```
struct Base
{
...
protected:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Base>> providers;
    ...
public:
    ...

    void subscribe_to(std::shared_ptr<Base> &src);

    ...
};

void Base::subscribe_to(std::shared_ptr<Base> &src)
{
    if (src) {
        providers.push_back(src);
    }
}

void Base::do_work()
{
    ...
    for(std::weak_ptr<Base> &wp : providers) {
        std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = wp.lock();
        if (ptr) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}

...

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> global_vec;
```

> Base's destructor is invoked, but the pointers are valid

No, they are not **valid**, since the object being pointed to was destroyed.  The pointers are simply left dangling, pointing to the old memory, and are not `nullptr` like you are expecting.

> you can even get access to data members from them

It is **undefined behavior** to access members of an object after it has been destroyed.